# If $X=\beta\mathbb{N}$ and $M$ is countable then $X_M$ is a metric space. (Elementary submodels)

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, model-theory

I imagine this question is very simple but there must be something that I'm missing.

If $M$ is an elementary submodel of the universe, and I have a topological space $(X,\tau)\in M$. I can define a new topological space $X_M = (X\cap M, \tau\cap M)$. (The set $ \tau\cap M$ is not necesarrily a topology but it is a basis for one.)

It supposedly clear that if $M$ is countable and $X$ is $\beta\mathbb{N}$ then $(X\cap M, \tau\cap M)$ is a countable metric space.

I don't know how to verify the claim. I know it is countable and second countable, but I do not know if it is compact or something else like this that will give me a metric.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Any second countable and regular ($T_3$) space is metrisable by Urysohn's metrisation theorem.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Is it obvious that $X_M$ is still $T_3$?

Comment: A subspace of a $T_3$ space is $T_3$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But the topology $\tau\cap M$ generates on $X\cap M$ is not necessarily the subspace topology.

Comment: "Every point has a neighbourhood base of closed sets" is equivalent to $T_3$ and might get preserved by elementarity?

Comment: Note that this is not quite $\tau\cap M$, but rather the intersections of sets in this intersection with $M$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the following works (it's a bit late where I am, but here goes):

First of all, let's clear up what the space is. As Asaf points out, the base is a bit messier than you've described: the space $(X_M, \tau_M)$ is $(X\cap M, \{U\cap M: U\in\tau\cap M\})$. Right off the bat, this tells us that if $M$ is countable then $(X_M,\tau_M)$ is a countable second-countable space, regardless of what $(X,\tau)$ is.

Now we want to argue that if $X=\beta\mathbb{N}$ and $\tau$ is as usual, the space $\mathcal{X}_M=(X_M,\tau_M)$ will be $T_3$; by [Urysohn's metrization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem#Metrization_theorems) (as observed by Henno Brandsma in a comment), the result will follow. So we need to show that $\mathcal{X}_M$ is Hausdorff and regular.

- $\mathcal{X}_M$ is Hausdorff: given distinct ultrafilters $p, q\in X\cap M$, there must be a set distinguishing them in $M$ - that is, some $a\subseteq\omega$ with $a\in p$ but $\omega\setminus a\in q$. But then the open sets $[a]$ and $[\omega\setminus a]$ (where "$[x]$" denotes the set of ultrafilters containing $x$) forms a pair of open sets in $\mathcal{X}_M$ separating $p$ and $q$.
- $\mathcal{X}_M$ is regular: we want to show that if $p\in X_M$ and $C\subseteq X_M$ is closed, then there are neighborhoods separating $p$ and $C$. Since the complement of $C$ is open, we can find some basic open set containing $p$ which is disjoint from $C$; considering the topology, what this means is that we can find some $a\subseteq\omega$ with $a\in M$ and $x\in p$ (i.e. $p\in [a]$) but with $a\not\in q$ for any $q\in C$. But then $[\omega\setminus a]$ is a basic open neighborhood containing $C$ which is disjoint from $[a]$ (which contains $p$).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I think you didn't finish your comment.

Comment: The structure $(\beta \Bbb N\cap M, \tau\cap M) $ given in the Q is not a top'l space if $M$ is transitive because then $\tau \cap M\supset \{\{n\}: n\in \Bbb N\} .$  A topology $T$ with $T\supset \{\{n\}:n\in \Bbb N\}$ must contain every subset of $\Bbb N,$  but $\tau\cap M$ is only countable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet No countable elementary submodel is transitive (they all contain $\omega_1$ as an element).

Comment: Also, in my pair $(A, \sigma)$ $\sigma$ is meant to just be a *base* for a topology - that might not have been clear in what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: I was  pointing out an error in the Q.

Comment: @Daniel: The first time the word "transitive" appears on this page is in your comment above...

Comment: @AsafKaragila. I know. I was pointing out that in the Q, the statement that $(\beta \Bbb N\cap M,\tau\cap M)$ is a top'l space may  be false if $M$ happens to be transitive (which is, of course, a stronger hypothesis than  the existence of a countable  elementary sub-model of $V$.